# Cost for teletype type B (TTY) message exchange over SITA network

Tags: commercial-aviation, cost, data-link

Does anyone know which party (sender or receiver) bears the cost of sending TTY messages over the SITA network that are commonly used between airlines, GDSs and different vendors. Thanks.